# Scope of javascript variable using FB API Jquery, Javascript

Tags: jquery, facebook, javascript

Here is what I am working with, I have simplified it a little:

```
if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        response.id;

        user_id = response.id; // I thought I could at least access it below if it was defined globally...

    });     

    var friend_list = [];
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {

        $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {

            friend_list.push(friend.id);

        });

        user_friend_list = friend_list.toString();

    });  


    alert("user id:"+user_id+"friend list:"+user_friend_list); // Here is where I would like these two variables to show up

} else {
    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization

}
```

probably for some obvious reason (due to my poor javascript and jquery) I cannot capture the variables. If you provide an answer please explain a little so I can gain insight and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me', function(data) {
        var user_id = data.id;
        FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            var friend_list = [];
            for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                friend_list.push(response.data[i].id);
            }
            //user_friend_list = friend_list.join(",");
            alert("user id:" + user_id + "friend list:" + friend_list.join(","));
        });
    });
}
else {
    alert("no access granted");
}
```

Altered bits and pieces of code. Comment if you have a problem with this solution.

Comment: I see. Are the alterations just to avoid not needed jquery?

Comment: these are the alterations i did. 1.removed the `response.id`( whats it doing there? ) 2. making the 2nd api call at the callback of the first method. ( should do it like this if you want user_id in this function ) 3. changing $.each to for loop as per FB API documentation(i dont see any difference in our methods there) 4. using join instead of toString() 4. declaring the variables with a different scope (i have changed the scope to a narrower one now) 5. changing the name of one callback parameter to data. I was hoping to save all these typing :)

Answer (score 0):

The only place you can assume these values are defined is in the callback functions provided as second arguments. This is bescause the api() method is asynchronous.

You may end with some code like :

```
if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        // Now first asyncrhonous call is over, let's do the second one
        response.id;
        user_id = response.id; // I thought I could at least access it below if it was defined globally...
        var friend_list = [];
        FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {
            // Now second asynchronous call is over, we have both values defined.
            $.each(response.data, function (index, friend) {
                friend_list.push(friend.id);
            });

            user_friend_list = friend_list.toString();


            alert("user id:" + user_id + "friend list:" + user_friend_list); // Here is where I would like these two variables to show up
        });
    });

} else {
    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
}
```